# Python - Convert julian date to month

Tags: python, date, julian-date

I have a series of filenames which I need to process and they have year and Julian day in their filename, e.g. `A1998237.tif`.

How can I group these files based on their names, by month (e.g. Jan, Feb ...)?

This is a pre-procedure and after this I will read this files into memory. Then I will take the average of matrices associated with each of this files to produce monthly matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse out the julian day, file each filename into a dictionary for that month:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os.path

# months from 0 to 11
files_by_month = [[] for _ in range(12)]

for filename in filenames:
    dt = datetime.strptime(os.path.splitext(filename)[0][1:], '%Y%j')
    files_by_month[dt.month - 1].append(filename)
```

`files_by_month` uses 0-based indexing to store a list per month; January is 0, etc.

This assumes that the filename always starts with *one* letter, followed by the year + julian year day, followed by the extension. If these assumptions are incorrect you need to provide more information on what sort of patterns there are in your filenames.

Demo for your sample filename:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import os.path
>>> filename = 'A1998237.tif'
>>> datetime.strptime(os.path.splitext(filename)[0][1:], '%Y%j')
datetime.datetime(1998, 8, 25, 0, 0)
```

which would be filed in the 'august' bucket, `files_by_month[7]`.

Comment: Thanks for the respond. It took me a while to get this to run properly. I had to change datetime.strptime to time.strptime. Looked it up from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070193/why-is-datetime-strptime-not-working-in-this-simple-example)

Comment: How can I preserve the path after the grouping?

Comment: insert `os.path.join(directoryname, filename)`; [`os.listdir()` lists relative names only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535188/no-such-file-or-directory-while-trying-to-read-files-in-a-directory-python).